# Java 7 -> Java 8: AES Causes exception: "BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded" in conjunction with BufferedReader & ZipStreams

Tags: java, encryption, aes, java-8

We instantiate the cipher with the following statement:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES");
```

This works in java 7 (1.7_45) but no longer works in Java 8 (1.8_25). We pass the `cipher` to a `CipherInputStream` and use the streams to read/write data. The actual exception occurs during `close`.

**EDIT:**

A quick look at the JDK code shows that the BadPaddingException is rethrown and in 7 it was ignored:

JDK 7: CipherInputStream.close:

```
 try {
  this.cipher.doFinal();
} catch (BadPaddingException var2) {
  ;
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException var3) {
  ;
}
```

JDK 8: CipherInputStream.close:

```
try {
    if(!this.done) {
      this.cipher.doFinal();
    }
  } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException var2) {
    if(this.read) {
      throw new IOException(var2);
    }
  }
```

The question is how to avoid a BadPaddingException in the first place?

**EDIT 2:**

After doing some research and experimentation we came to the following test program:

```
public final class CipherSpike2 {

  private static final byte[] SECRET_KEY = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};

  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    encryptDecrypt(511);
    encryptDecrypt(512);
  }

  private static void encryptDecrypt(int i)
  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {

    byte[] clearText = generateClearText(i);
    System.out.println("Clear text length: " + clearText.length);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE));
    cos.write(clearText);
    cos.close();

    final byte[] content = bos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("written bytes: " + content.length);

    CipherInputStream
    inputStream =
    new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content), getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE));

    inputStream.read();
    inputStream.close();
 }

 private static byte[] generateClearText(int size) {
    return new byte[size];
  }

  private static Cipher getCipher(int encryptMode)
  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY, "AES");
    cipher.init(encryptMode, key);
    return cipher;
  }
}
```

First, the program writes 511 bytes which results in a 512 byte long "file content". 
We read exactly one byte. The CipherInputStream reads the data in a 512 byte chunk, so every byte is read and we can close the stream.

Next, we create a content of 512 bytes. This gets padded to 528. If we now read only one byte, we have some bytes left and if we close the stream now it crashes with the given exception.

Now this problem is especially problematic in conjunction with ZipStreams: The encrypted content is in a previous step zipped with a ZipOutputStream and read with a ZipInputStream. It seems, that the ZipInputStream does not consume the same amount of bytes as it has previously written.

It seems that the only solution is to catch the BadPaddingException in the close().(?) From an API view point it seems weird to me, that I cannot close a stream without exception regardless of the number of bytes I've read.

**EDIT 3 ZipStream elaboration:**

In our application we read a bunch of encrypted text files. So the consturction for the streams looks like this:

```
BufferedReader/Writer -> InputStreamReader/Writer -> ZipInputStream/Output -> CipherInputStream/Output -> Underlying File Stream
```

We read the content of the file with a "traditional" while (reader.readLine != null) loop until we reach EOF. After that we try to close the file. But sometimes this results in an exception in Java 8 - see above (-:. It seems, that the ZipOutputStream writes more bytes then the ZipInputStreams  consumes, but I don't looked at the code yet.

Comment: An example code reproducing the problem would be nice

Comment: I assume that an internal change in the JDK 8 causes the problem, thats why I didn't provide one. The runs fine on JDK 7 but if I switch to JDK 8 it crashes.

Comment: @morpheus05 There's not enough information in your question to determine the cause of your problem. `BadPaddingException` can be triggered by a number of issues, including the wrong key or specifying the wrong padding. Please provide more information about where the encrypted data is coming from and the key. A self-contained example that demonstrates the problem will be ideal.

Comment: I added a second edit to the post. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: It's a judgement call but I like the behavior the way it is. If you are going to prematurely close a Cipher*Stream you just have to deal with the possible BadPaddingException. I'm not sure I understand your ZipStreams comment. It just sounds like 'ur doin' it rong on that one.

Comment: @GregS I elaborated on the ZipStream stuff. But I don't understand why its nice to have this behavior: Lets say we have a file with meta information at the start and some data. I read the meta information I decide i don't want to read the rest of the file. With every other stream I now can close the stream and be done with it, CipherInputStream behaves differently here - which I find annoying but I guess there is a good reason to throw the exception(?)

Comment: You chose to layer the stream over a cipher instance with padding. If you choose that padding mode then you've told the cipher object that calling doFinal should check the padding and throw an exception if it is incorrect. So I think everything is working correctly. You can chose a cipher with no padding, and manage the padding yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 1.8 `CipherInputStream` throws a `BadPaddingException` if you don't completely consume the stream. This may be the case when using `ZipInputStream`, since consuming a zip in streaming fashion doesn't need to read the zip index at the end of the file.

I recommend wrapping the `CipherInputStream` in a facade implementation of `InputStream` that ignores `BadPaddingException` when delegating the `close()` method. Don't do this if authentication of the contents of the stream is required for your use case, of course, or if some kind of timing oracle attack is possible.

Comment: The files are encrypted during build time and unpacked during execution. We implemented this solution and til now it works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have hit https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061619. There was a good reason for the change in behaviour (see http://blog.philippheckel.com/2014/03/01/cipherinputstream-for-aead-modes-is-broken-in-jdk7-gcm/)

You should explicitly specify the padding in your cipher instance (e.g. `AES/GCM/NoPadding`, but check the suitability for your application. Incorrect padding is behind a number of attacks on SSL)

Comment: I explained a bit more what the actual problem is if you wanna look at it.